# mysqli_stmt to return a result object

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When querying using `mysqli_stmt::prepare()` and `execute()`, it will not return the result set. But we need to access using the `mysqli_stmt:fetch()` on the stmt object. There is one function in the php manual called `mysqli_stmt::get_result()` that will return the result set into a variable we define, but when I use it, it gives me undefined method error. The manual say it is probably in SVC which I am not sure what.

The codes:

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
$stmt =  $conn->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("select * from users where u_id = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Edit :**
I know I can use bind_result() and fetch() function to retrieve the record like :

```
$stmt->bind_result($column1, $column2, $column3);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "Column 1: $column1\n";
    echo "Column 2: $column2\n";
    echo "Column 3: $column3\n";
}
```

But, my objective is to get the result set (the resource type object) after I execute, something like this:

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

so I can use the normal `mysqli::fetch_object` on the result set

```
$conn->fetch_object($result);
```

Is there any way to achieve this? thanks

**Update:**
The [get_result](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) function is exactly what I need, but it's not working on my PHP

Comment: Could you post an excerpt of your code showing how you use the mentioned functions ? It should probably look like the example provided by http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php, with `mysqli_stmt::bind_result()` and `mysqli_stmt::fetch()`, I presume...

Comment: yes, it's exactly like that example. Updated the question with the code

Comment: yeah, I read the example. I know how to fetch. I don't have problem fetching it. you guys misunderstood my question! I'll update my question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you do not want to use `mysqli_stmt::fetch()` but `mysqli_result::fetch_*()`, I guess it will be a little cumbersome.

http://www.joekolba.com/node/2

Alternatively, use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Google search keywords: mysqli_result prepared statement.

Comment: great.. that's cumbersome. will take a look on PDO. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in the following way:

```
$stmt->prepare("select * from users where u_id = ? ");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($columns['column_name1'], $columns['column_name2'], $columns['column_name3']);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
  $row = (object) $columns;
}
```

That comes quite near the FETCH_OBJECT method. You can access all the data of one row via $row->column_name1 etc. Of course you would have to update the associative columns-array, when you alter your table and change names. But it works quite well for me. Didn't want to switch to PDO - considering the fact I switched to MYSQLi just some days ago ;)

Answer (score 0):

To enable the method mysqli_stmt::get_result(), you need to use the mysqlnd (MySQL Native Driver) extension: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php

For some reason, this concrete method is not implemented with the more usual libmysqlclient. In my debian server (and also on my ubuntu desktop) this amounted to run:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mysqlnd
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call `bind_result` to tell mysqli which variables should hold the columns. Then every time you call fetch, those variables will be automatically filled in, and you can access them like normal. See the code below (not sure if it works, ymmv).

```
$conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if($stmt = $conn->prepare('select * from users where u_id = ?'))
{
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $param);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($column1, $column2, $column3);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo "Column 1: $column1\n";
        echo "Column 2: $column2\n";
        echo "Column 3: $column3\n";
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: Also if u_id is an integer, as I suspect, then change the `"s"` to `"i"` on `bind_param`.

Comment: this is not answering my question... This is the normal way, it works fine, but I want it to return the resource type object instead of need to access it with the bind_result and fetch().